# Angular 2 importing node_modules not adding to build

Tags: javascript, angular, build, node-modules

I'm having trouble with some components running in MS IE 10/11.
And according to this arcticle from Angular.io (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html) I need to import an external script.

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

Which I placed in my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <base href="/">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">
        ...
        <script src="../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
 </html>
```

But when i build for production it doesn't add it to the build, it just leaves it there ending in a script not found error when running the application.

I'm probably missing something but I don't know what.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Angular doesn't read your index.html file to figure out what dependencies it needs to bundle up.  The index.html file is largely untouched when you get to the build phase.  You have to specify this as a dependency through the proper system channels.  However, the details to do that can actually vary wildly, and it depends on how your build is being managed.  Are you using the angular cli?  Did you download an angular seed project (probably with either webpack or systemjs)?  Basically, there are a variety of ways to manage the build process, and the answer depends on how your build is managed.

Comment: I'm using Angular Cli with webpack, it's a large application build from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.angular-cli.json` file, locate (or create) the `"scripts"` key in the definition for your app, and add an entry in the array for the `shim.js` script, e.g.:

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"
],
```

Restart your `ng serve` or rebuild your bundles and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CSS files and JS files in the angular-cli.json file. If you are not using angular-cli in this case you need to configure in the build tool which you are using